# MPD fails streams after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: sound, streaming, stream, mpd

My apologies in advance if my reporting is not fully compliant with the standards - I'm a bit of a beginner in Linux.

I've been using MPD (standard 0.19.xx) in Ubuntu for a while without any troubles, but after a recent upgrade streams (Shoutcast streams, like http://icecast.omroep.nl/3fm-bb-mp3) have started "stuttering". Local files play without issues, and using a different player (Rythmbox) the streams play just fine.

- The `mpd.log` was not showing any feedback, even after setting `mpd.conf` to log Verbose.
- After upgrading `mpd` to 20.12, `mpd.log` started reporting:

On start:

```
Aug 09 11:03 : exception: OutputThread could not get realtime scheduling, continuing anyway: sched_setscheduler failed: Operation not permitted
```

When playing streams:

```
Aug 09 11:07 : player: Decoder is too slow; playing silence to avoid xrun
```

One hint that might point at the cause (but I'm really not sure) was the following after running `apt install --reinstall mpd`

```
Error in '/usr/share/doc-base/mpd', line 7: all 'Format' sections are invalid.
Note: 'install-docs --verbose --check file_name' may give more details about the above error.
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mpd (0.20.12-1~ppa1~xenial1) ...
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script 'mpd' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script 'mpd' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

Any further info I can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I found the reason: a malfunctioning high-voltage protector in the network was causing issues (strangely enough just with MPD and with CURL).